# How to remove xmlns="" from the xml tag

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am writing the following code to add a heading tag to the existing xml.

```
            String pagemetadata = curPage.Metadata.OuterXml;
            XmlDocument pageMeta = new XmlDocument();
            pageMeta.LoadXml(pagemetadata);

            XmlNode Metadata = pageMeta.FirstChild as XmlNode;
            XmlNode headingNode = pageMeta.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "heading", null);
            headingNode.InnerText = HTML_BrowserTitle;
            Metadata.AppendChild(headingNode);
```

I am able to add the tag as shown below. But how can i remove xmlns="" from the tag?

```
<title xmlns="">    </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the namespace of the document is different to the namespace of the element. Try creating the XML Node with `CreateNodeNS` instead of `CreateNode`, and make sure it is in the same namespace as its parent/main document.